# fastText python implementation creating training and testing set

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp, fasttext

I am webscraping and I saved my utf-8 to a csv, cleaned it and now I am trying to create my training and testing files to be able to use Facebooks fastText, right now this is what I have and it is giving me an error

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

y_all = df["normalized"]
X_all = df.drop('normalized', axis = 1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_all, y_all, `test_size=0.3, random_state=1)`
import fasttext as ft
classifier = ft.supervised(X_train, y_train)
```

and this is the error it is returning, this is fastText for windows in jupyter notebook

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-1f4fa41d367f> in <module>()
----> 1 classifier = ft.supervised(X_train, y_train)

fasttext/fasttext.pyx in fasttext.fasttext.supervised (fasttext/fasttext.cpp:6665)()

fasttext/fasttext.pyx in fasttext.fasttext.train_wrapper (fasttext/fasttext.cpp:4732)()

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py in isfile(path)
     28     """Test whether a path is a regular file"""
     29     try:
---> 30         st = os.stat(path)
     31     except OSError:
     32         return False

TypeError: argument should be string, bytes or integer, not DataFrame
```

Comment: Try doing `y_all = df["normalized"].values`  
`X_all = df.drop('normalized', axis = 1).values`

Answer (score 0):

@kwashington122 I think the way you are using supervised is wrong. fasttext.supervised is a classifier that takes as input the training file that should contain labeled data, something like 
X_train:

> text1 label_x
>   text2 label_y

and you will need to specify the label prefix so that fasttext can capture the different labels you have. 
`model = fasttext.supervised(X_train,'model', label_prefix='label_')` fasttext will detect 2 labels in my example x and y (since I specified label_ as prefix to the labels).

Then in order to predict or test the classifier on a new set of data you just need to do this :
`model.test(X_test)` 
or if you want to predict label for a text or sentences do the following:

```
model.predict(X_test) ## where text has no labels.
```

My answer is a bit late sorry just hit the question while looking for an answer to my problem.